# Data Binding in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-binding

I know it would be a basic question but I'm a newbie to ASP.Net MVC. I have fetched data from database using LINQ but there is an issue. I wanna bind that data with input fields of a  customized webform. (I'm using MVC). I wanna populate the input fields of webform with fetched data. I'm using EF Database first approach. 
My Controller and view is attached.

**Controller ActionMethod**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        AutoRTGSEntities_1 dc = new AutoRTGSEntities_1();
        //dc.policies.Where(cb => cb.Section_Key.Contains("SenderBIC"));
        return View(dc.policies.Where(cb => cb.Policy_Section.Contains("RTGS")).ToList()); //get RTGS policy section data

    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Swift_MT_103.policy>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div> @Model{ @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.data_Value)) } </div> 
<div> <input type="text" name="ReceiverBIC" id="ReceiverBIC" /> </div>
```

Rest is HTML and CSS. Snap is attached.
 [image: Customized View]

Comment: Where is the problem statement?

Comment: I wanna populate the input fields with fetched data.

Comment: That is what you want to do but you have not stated what is the problem. What have you tried and where are you having issues?

Comment: I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand and reproduce your problem.

Comment: While it may be a basic issue you need to provide the relevant information for us to be able to help you.

Comment: I've already stated it. I have fetched data from database and now I wanna populate/bind data to the input fields of customized view. I don't know how to do it. How to map data with input fields.

Comment: Since you said `I wanna populate the input fields with fetched data`, do you mean you want to fill UnitID textbox with the UnitID value from `policies` table?

Comment: Data Binding works best through Razor Views and dedicated View Models. Without any of those, you'll have a very hard time binding the data. If you have HTML only, you cannot bind (on server side). I'd suggest to grab a copy of the HTML and replace all Input Fields (e.g. `<input type="text" name="accountno" value="something" />` with Razor counterparts, e.g. `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AccountNo)`)

Comment: Exactly @ekad this is what I want

Comment: @AhmadBinShafaat Show a snippet of the raw code for the view. (for example, the first 4 fields at the top) The suggestion by thmshd is accurate.

Comment: `@model IEnumerable<Swift_MT_103.policy>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    }  <div>
                        <div>
                            @Model{ 
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.data_Value))
                            }             
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text"  name="ReceiverBIC" id="ReceiverBIC" />
                        @Nkosi

Comment: You should edit your question and add the html code of the first 4 textboxes at the top, then mention something like "I want to fill UnitID textbox with the value from column x of policy table". That should be enough to clarify what you need. The solution is the suggestion by @thmshd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a **very basic** example of how to this. Let's say you have following class:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-mailaddress")]
    public string E-mail { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller you get the user:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var user = Db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    if(user != null)
    {
        return View(user);
    }

    //Return to the 'Error' view as no user was found
    return View("Error");
}
```

You also need a View to show everything on screen. Make it a strongly typed view, this way you can pass a Model to it. This class will hold all data you want to pass to the view. Code of the view:

```
//This line lets the view know which class represents the model
@model User

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
```

Using the Razor syntax instead of plain HTML it is very easy to construct and bind your form elements to the corresponding data. In this case the label will show the value of the `Display` attribute in the `User` class and the values of the user will be filled in the textboxes.

More reading:

- [**Getting started with ASP.NET MVC 5**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/)
- [**ASP.NET MVC Overview**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx)

**Update:**

In case you have a list of objects, you need to enumerate them in the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

@foreach (var value in Model)
{
    <div>@value</div>
}
```

And if the model is a class and has a property that is a list:

```
//Let's say a user has lots of names
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
}

//View:
@model User

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id)

@foreach (var name in Model.Names)
{
    <div>@name</div> 
}
```

Comment: I've already used this line `@model IEnumerable<Swift_MT_103.policy>` at the top. Now what would be the proper way to populate a textbox? ` @model policy
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.data_Value))` is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement a correct ASP.NET MVC architecture. To get this completed, you'll need to use proper Razor (`.cshtml` type) Syntax in your Views. Best practice:

1. Create a dedicated ViewModel class in the `Model` directory. You might call it `CustomerCreditTransferViewModel` for example. It should contain all Properties you want to display/edit anywhere on the page.
2. Once you selected your data from your DBContext in your Action, create an instance of `CustomerCreditTransferViewModel` and populate all fields from the result.
3. Update your View to use `@model CustomerCreditTransferViewModel` instead of `Swift_MT_103.policy` (believe me, this is going to make your live much easier in future)
4. Copy-paste your raw HTML Code into the page and start looking for all Fields you want to bind, e.g. Text fields (`<input type="text" name="accountno" value="" />`) and replace them with the Razor Syntax for Data Binding (`@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AccountNo)`). If done correctly, they should be populated now.
5. Next step is probably the POST. Follow the base MVC Post technique from the Tutorials. Ensure that the Posted Value is of type `CustomerCreditTransferViewModel`) again, so you can easily validate values and map back to type of `Swift_MT_103.policy`.